# Modify contents of a listBox from another class

Tags: c#

So I have a main screen that contains a listBox that displays the names of the data segments that I am working with and modifying. From another class, I am adding data to the list that this list box gets all of its data from. What I need is for the other class to be able to update the listBox from a button click method.
I've tried creating a public instance of the class containing the listBox like so:

```
static class Program
{
    public static MainWindow mainWin;
    ...
    //got this idea from another question
    Application.Run(mainWin);
    ...
```

The problem is that when I try running the program, it hangs and acts as if it is waiting for my responses. How should I best access the listBox from the other class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found my problem. And I will admit my solution is probably not the best but it is the first that I found that works. The main issue with it hanging was the variable was assigned a value of null. So I assigned out a value after calling 'Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault'  and it ran correctly. The next issue that I ran into was a problem of access levels. The listBox was marked as private which I changed to public

Comment: Yes. Either make it public or public static or just send it to a method by reference or out by value.